# getting ID from URL with React router (match)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im trying to make a detail page. So im trying to get the id from the url for example localhost:3000/65 (the 65 is the id). Im using React Router. Im trying to get it first working with just a simple console log.

detail.js

```
const Detail = ({ match }) => {
 
 console.log(match);

  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log(match);
    fetchData(URL, config.KEY).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      setDetails(response);
    });
  }, []);

  const [detail, setDetails] = useState([]);

  return <div> detail </div>;
};

export default Detail;
```

this is what my router looks like

```
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/:id" component={Detail} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Can anybody help me with this problem so i can get the "id"

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to access the route parameter is through the useParams hook from React Router like this:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const ChildComponent = () => {
 const { id } = useParams();
 return (
   <div>
     ID: {id}
   </div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

start by changing this typing error,

```js
 <Route parth="/:id" component={Detail} />
```

to

```js
 <Route path="/:id" component={Detail} />
```

Comment: that is a really stupid mistake, sadly it wont fix my problem